# When importing from keras in Jupyter, getting error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'message_types_by_name'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, import, jupyter

I am trying to do several imports from the keras library. I am doing this on a Jupyter notebook using an Anaconda installed Python. I have used keras before fine, and I just checked for updates but found none. Here are the import statements.

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import SimpleRNN
from keras.layers import Embedding
```

I get a warning when I run this that says 'Using TensorFlow backend. Then I get a long error output that ends with 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'message_types_by_name'. Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in "from keras.utils import to\_categorical"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67018079/error-in-from-keras-utils-import-to-categorical)

Comment: I ended up solving the problem by just restarting the kernel and calling all of my imports in the first cell of my notebook. I am not sure what the actual problem was,  but there seemed to be some TensorFlow process that was started that affected the imports.

Answer (score -1):

Since Tensorflow supports Keras as High level API, suggested way to import Keras libraries/modules is as below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tf.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tf.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tf.keras.models import Sequential
from tf.keras.layers import Dense
from tf.keras.layers import SimpleRNN
from tf.keras.layers import Embedding
```

Check the document from Keras [here](https://keras.io/getting_started/) for reference.